# Frequent Updating of GUI WxPYTHON

Tags: multithreading, wxpython, publish-subscribe

I have a piece of code which has to get executed every 100ms and update the GUI. When I am updating the GUI - I am pressing a button, which calls a thread and in turn it calls a target function. The target function gives back the message to the GUI thread using pub sub as follows.

```
wx.CallAfter(pub.sendMessage, "READ EVENT", arg1=data, arg2=status_read) # This command line is in my target function

        pub.subscribe(self.ReadEvent, "READ EVENT") # This is in my GUI file - whihc calls the following function

 def ReadEvent(self, arg1, arg2):
        if arg2 == 0:
            self.MessageBox('The program did not properly read data from MCU \n Contact the Program Developer')
            return

        else:
            self.data = arg1

            self.firmware_version_text_control.Clear()
            #fwversion = '0x' + ''.join('{:02X}'.format(j) for j in reversed(fwversion))
            self.firmware_version_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'FwVersion')))
            # Pump Model
            self.pump_model_text_control.Clear()
            self.pump_model_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'ModelName')))
            # Pump Serial Number
            self.pump_serial_number_text_control.Clear()
            self.pump_serial_number_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'SerialNum'))[:10]) # Personal Hack to not to display the AA , AB and A0
            # Pressure GAIN
            self.gain_text_control.Clear()
            self.gain_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'PresGain')))
            # Pressure OFFSET Offset
            self.offset_text_control.Clear()
            self.offset_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'PresOffset')))
            #Wagner Message:
            #self.status_text.SetLabel(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'WelcomeMsg')))
            # PUMP RUNNING OR STOPPED

            if PumpState(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'PumpState')) == 1:
                self.led6.SetBackgroundColour('GREEN')
            elif PumpState(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'PumpState')) == 0:
                self.led6.SetBackgroundColour('RED')
            else:
                self.status_text.SetLabel(PumpState(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'PumpState')))
            # PUMP RPM
            self.pump_rpm_text_control.Clear()
            if not self.new_model_value.GetValue():
                self.pump_rpm_text_control.AppendText("000")
            else:
                self.pump_rpm_text_control.AppendText(str(self.sheet_num.cell_value(self.sel+1,10)*(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'FrqQ5'))/65536))
            # PUMP PRESSURE
            self.pressure_text_control.Clear()
            self.pressure_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'PresPsi')))
            # ON TIME   -- HOURS AND MINUTES --- EDITING IF YOU WANT
            self.on_time_text_control.Clear()
            self.on_time_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'OnTime')))
            # JOB ON TIME - HOURS AND MINUTES - EDITING IF YOU WANT
            self.job_on_time_text_control.Clear()
            self.job_on_time_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'JobOnTime')))
            # LAST ERROR ----- RECHECK THIS AGAIN
            self.last_error_text_control.Clear()
            self.last_error_text_control.AppendText(str(SortAndDecode(self.data, 'LastErr')))
            # LAST ERROR COUNT --- RECHECK THIS AGAIN
            self.error_count_text_control.Clear()
            self.error_count_text_control.AppendText("CHECK THIS")
```

As you can see my READEVENT is very big and it takes a while for the GUI to take enough time to successfully do all these things. My problem here is, when my GUI is updating the values of TEXTCTRL it is going unresponsive - I cannot do anything else. I cant press a button or enter data or anything else. My question is if there is a better way for me to do this, so my GUI wont go unresponsive. I dont know how I can put this in a different thread as all widgets are in the main GUI. But that also requires keep creating threads every 100ms - which is horrible. Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

1. How long does `SortAndDecode` take? What about the `str()` of the result?  Those may be good candidates for keeping that processing in the worker thread instead of the UI thread, and passing the values to the UI thread pre-sorted-and-decoded.
2. You can save a little time in each iteration by calling `ChangeValue` instead of `Clear` and `AppendText`. Why do two function calls for each text widget instead of just one?  Function calls are relatively expensive in Python compared to other Python code.
3. If it's possible that the same value will be sent that was sent on the last iteration then adding checks for the new value matching the old value and skipping the update of the widget could potentially save lots of time.  Updating widget values is very expensive compared to leaving them alone.
4. Unless there is a hard requirement for 100ms updates you may want to try 150 or 200.  Fewer updates per second may be fast enough for most people, especially since it's mostly textual.  How much text can you read in 100ms?
5. If you are still having troubles with having more updates than the UI thread can keep up with, then you may want to use a different approach than pubsub and `wx.CallAfter`.  For example you could have the worker thread receive and process the data and then add an object to a `Queue.Queue` and then call `wx.WakeUpIdle()`.  In the UI thread you can have an `EVT_IDLE` event handler that checks the queue and pulls the first item out of the queue, if there are any, and then updates the widgets with that data.  This will give the benefit of not flooding the pending events list with events from too many `wx.CallAfter` calls, and you can also do things like remove items from your data queue if there are too many items in it.

Comment: Interesting answers. I am more intrigued by point 3 and 5. Point 3 - Would not that have more code to run? and slow down the process more?

Point 5: Could you please give me an example. I tried the queue like a month ago and failed very badly as it is giving only one element of a 192 length numpy array. I would appreciate if you could give me an example on using wx.WakeupIdle